# The generate_address() returns a unique address?

Tags: wallet, chrysalis, python

I was wondering if it's possible in my app where i have registered users, to provide a new wallet address for them to transfer funds while making sure that address is unique to the user i gave the address to.

That way i think i could relate a transfer to that address to that specific user while listening to new transactions in the app wallet.

Is there any chance of other user receiveing the same address in the future?

I'm using the generate_address() method in wallet.rs binding for python.

Answer (score 4):

I think the generate_address() function will generate a new address everytime is called. You could also evaluate creating a unique account for each user depending on your use case.

Comment: The problem with creating a unique account is that is receive this error message: "can't create accounts when the latest account doesn't have message history and balance".

Answer (score -1):

have a look at the [exchange guide](https://chrysalis.docs.iota.org/guides/exchange_guide.html), as it can be source of inspiration for such an implementation.

Comment: An answer on StackExchange sites should not only include a link to an external reference. Links tend to go down after a few years and the content becomes useless... Having an additional link as source or for more details is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @mihi